# RavenDB.Database and Metrics.Net conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net, ravendb, metrics

I have an Asp.Net Core project where I'm using RavenDB document database. Everything was working fine until I added Metrics.NET (https://github.com/etishor/Metrics.NET) to the project. Since then the following issue is happening when loading the project:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
The type initializer for 'Raven.Abstractions.Util.MetricsTicker' threw an exception.
Could not load file or assembly 'metrics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ca6c6ef570198eba' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
```

It seems that RavenDB uses its own **metrics.dll** that has conflicts with the one from Metrics.Net when the assemblies are loading.
Is there any way to resolve this? Does someone has had this issue? Can I say to Nuget or the project that moves the RavenDB assemblies to a subfolder to avoid the conflicts?

I'm using RavenDB version 3.0.30155 and Metrics.Net version 0.3.7 Nugget packages.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after more investigation it was an issue on RavenDB. It has an internal custom Metrics.Net library that was what caused the conflict. The issue is here: http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-5321

It is fixed in the version 3.0.30156-Hotfix